# Kafka mirrormaker jmxtrans configuration file format

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, grafana, jmxtrans

I use jmxtrans to monitor kafka mirrormaker but my json format seems to have problems, the data can not be displayed

how to write this json file, thank

```
{
    "servers": [{
        "port": "5448",
        "host": "10.10.21.10",
        "queries": [{
                "obj": "kafka.consumer:type=ConsumerTopicMetrics,name=BytesInPerSec,topic=mirror_group-*",
                "attr": ["Count", "MeanRate", "OneMinuteRate"],
                "resultAlias": "mirror_group-*",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://10.10.21.10:8086",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "123",
                    "database": "jmxDB",
                    "tags": {
                        "application": "BytesInPerSec"
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.consumer:type=ConsumerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=mirror_group-*",
                "attr": ["Count", "MeanRate", "OneMinuteRate"],
                "resultAlias": "mirror_group-*",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://10.10.21.10:8086",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "123",
                    "database": "jmxDB",
                    "tags": {
                        "application": "MessagesInPerSec"
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.producer:type=ProducerRequestMetrics,name=ProducerRequestRateAndTimeMs,topic=mirror_group-*",
                "attr": ["Count", "Max", "Min", "50thPercentile", "75thPercentile", "95thPercentile"],
                "resultAlias": "mirror_group-*",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://10.10.21.10:8086",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "123",
                    "database": "jmxDB",
                    "tags": {
                        "application": "ProducerRequestRateAndTimeMs"
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                "obj": "kafka.producer:type=ProducerRequestMetrics,name=ProducerRequestSize,topic=mirror_group-*",
                "attr": ["Count", "Max", "Min", "50thPercentile", "75thPercentile", "95thPercentile"],
                "resultAlias": "mirror_group-*",
                "outputWriters": [{
                    "@class": "com.googlecode.jmxtrans.model.output.InfluxDbWriterFactory",
                    "url": "http://10.10.21.10:8086",
                    "username": "root",
                    "password": "123",
                    "database": "jmxDB",
                    "tags": {
                        "application": "ProducerRequestSize"
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

[image: This is the kafka mirrormaker data information seen on jconsole]

I can't get the data from grafana

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks ,I have formatted it . can you help me ?

Comment: I have not used JMXTrans, and I don't know your Grafana or InfluxDB connection information. I might suggest trying it on a simpler Java example, as this question is probably unrelated to Kafka or MirrorMaker